# Find the missing gaps in between time intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a store table which has storename, agentname,date, shiftStartTime,shiftEndTime. I am trying to find if there is any store which has no agent present in store for any time-interval. The data should be grouped by store, date. below are the sample records from my data

```
STORE_NAME  DISTRICT REGION   NAME  WORK_DATE   ShftStTim   ShftEdTimeenter 

A0004         65    Mid-West    Abc 1/14/2016   12:30:00    12:59:59
A0004         65    Mid-West    Abc 1/14/2016   8:00:00     12:30:00
A0004         65    Mid-West    Abc 1/14/2016   12:59:59    15:59:59
A0004         65    Mid-West    xyz 1/14/2016   19:30:00    20:00:00
A0004         65    Mid-West    xyz 1/14/2016   15:00:00    19:30:00
A0004         65    Mid-West    xyz 1/14/2016   20:00:00    23:00:00
A0004         65    Mid-West    cde 1/14/2016   15:00:00    15:30:00
A0004         65    Mid-West    cde 1/14/2016   11:00:00    15:00:00
A0004         65    Mid-West    cde 1/14/2016   15:30:00    18:59:59
A0004         65    Mid-West    fgh 1/14/2016   15:00:00    15:30:00
A0004         65    Mid-West    fgh 1/14/2016   11:00:00    15:00:00
A0004         65    Mid-West    fgh 1/14/2016   15:30:00    18:59:59
A0005         64    Mid-West    jkl 1/14/2016   13:30:00    14:00:00
A0005         64    Mid-West    jkl 1/14/2016   9:59:59     13:30:00
A0005         64    Mid-West    jkl 1/14/2016   14:00:00    16:00:00
**A0005       64    Mid-West    jkl 1/14/2016   16:30:00    18:00:00**
```

if you see above example I want to get last row which tells us there is 30 min gap where there are no agents present or storename by date and duration of gap would also work. **The time range is not sequential**. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can we assume the e time ranges do not cross over midnight?

Comment: Are the start and end times entered simultaneously, or is there a period where only a start time is present for a row?

Comment: you could create a multi-dimensional array (24,60) and fill with the Hours,Mins in a day. {1,0},{1,1}....{1,59}, {2,0}.   Then go through the rows of data and remove the minutes covered by the duration of the shift and Redim.  Once all the rows have been covered the only thing that should remain in the array are the minutes that were not removed by completed shifts.  If you wanted to include seconds, you would need to do (24,60,60)

Comment: Hey RBarry, yes time ranges do not cross over midnight.

Comment: DiscipleMichael - They are entered simultaneously.. there will not be any rows without start and end times. Thanks!

Comment: You got me wrong :) I said they don't cross over midnight.

Comment: @DiscipleMichael to be simple I just need to find missing gap between start time and end time by store and by day. From the scenario I understood that if we can take each start time and check if falls between any of the start time and end time by store by day then we can find missing gaps but I am unable to put my idea into SQL code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: dont happen to have a unique id for each row do you?

Comment: @JamieD77 No, we don't have uniqueID for each row :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you're trying to do.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table1 t1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                     FROM   Table1 t2
                     WHERE  t2.WORK_DATE = t1.WORK_DATE
                            AND t2.STORE_NAME = t1.STORE_NAME
                            AND (t1.ShftStTim BETWEEN t2.ShftStTim
                                              AND     t2.ShftEdTimeenter
                                 OR t1.ShftEdTimeenter BETWEEN t2.ShftStTim
                                                       AND     t2.ShftEdTimeenter) 
                            AND (t1.ShftStTim <> t2.ShftStTim
                                OR t1.ShftEdTimeenter <> t2.ShftEdTimeenter))
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle for this.. [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e23d7/1)  if you can add data to break it let me know.

It would be helpful if you had a UNIQUE ID to filter the NOT EXISTS, but you can add one by using ROW_NUMBER, and it might make this more accurate than using the TIME bit.  Performance might not be as good though.

**EDIT**

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [STORE_NAME]) AS Rn,
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [STORE_NAME], [WORK_DATE]) Cnt
    FROM    Table1
)
SELECT  *
FROM    cte t1
WHERE   Cnt > 1 -- only stores with more than one shift per day
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                     FROM   cte t2
                     WHERE  t1.Rn <> t2.Rn
                            AND t2.WORK_DATE = t1.WORK_DATE
                            AND t2.STORE_NAME = t1.STORE_NAME
                            AND (t1.ShftStTim BETWEEN t2.ShftStTim
                                              AND     t2.ShftEdTimeenter
                                 OR t1.ShftEdTimeenter BETWEEN t2.ShftStTim
                                                       AND     t2.ShftEdTimeenter)
                    )
```

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood.  This will give you the rows that dont' overlap.  Which means there was a previous gap.  It does NOT tell you what that gap is.  I thought you wanted the to identify the gap, not the first shift after a gap.  I don't think this will return the last row if the last shift was started between the previous, but ended early (leaving Gap at end of day)

Comment: @DiscipleMichael Yes Michael, they are not interested in seeing the overlapping rows they just want to know if there are any stores by each day where there is no agent present in the store. I know its confusing but I am trying my best to explain the scenario.

Comment: @Raj accidentally left the ID field in there from where i was testing it... should work without it.. i updated the answer

Comment: Yeah, it will.  The ID was just to make sure it wasn't considering the same row it's evaluating.

Comment: Also, this has no concern about what happens after the last shift.  Meaning, if you close at Midnight, and the last shift ended at 11pm (as long as it overlapped a previoius shift) you will see no entry for 11-midnight.

Comment: @JamieD77 I tried running the query you sent, its giving me the missing one's but also giving me some rows where there was agent present in the store.

Comment: @Raj.. Kindof hard to see how it could do that, but i only have your sample data to test with.. are the Time fields actually Time types or Varchar?  Same with Date field.. is it a Date or Varchar?

Comment: @JamieD77 
      'A0331 10 Northwest  Ashley 1/14/2016 12:00:00 15:59:59
      **A0331 10 Northwest  Destiny 1/14/2016 12:00:00 20:00:00**
      A0331 10 Northwest  Ashley 1/14/2016 15:59:59 16:30:00
      A0331 10 Northwest  Ashley 1/14/2016 16:30:00 20:00:00'            so for some reason its giving me second row as one of the result when I ran the query you sent but if we see there is no time gap where there was no agent

Comment: Remember, this doesn't give you the gap... it gives you the first row AFTER a gap occured.

Comment: @JamieD77 I am not sure where exactly I need to add parenthesis :( could you please send me updated query? I am new to t-sql

Comment: @JamieD77 Thanks! it worked this time but the only problem I am facing now is, its returning stores which has only one entry in a day. How can I get rid of those rows where there is only one entry per store per day

Comment: @Raj see the EDIT query

Comment: @JamieD77 Do you mind explaining me what the query is doing... So that I can get an understanding on how to approach this kind of scenarios. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It takes a row and looks to see if the Start Time is Between (>= or <=) another Start Time/End Time.. or if the End Time is Between another Start Time/End Time.. if either one of those things are true then it is an overlapping record, so the NOT EXISTS excludes that record.  The rest is just making sure you're looking at the right Date/Time to compare to by using the same Work_Date and Store_Name

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something similar although I was interested in coverage depth (how many employees on during each segment).  I came across a nice article that helped me get most of the way to my solution:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/calculating-gaps-between-overlapping-time-intervals-in-sql/